# VS2012 does not format the c# code after installing VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, formatting, visual-studio-2010

I have installed VS2012 first. Then I need to install VS2010 Express for Microsoft Micro Framework 4.2. After that VS2012 does not format the code.

I try repair VS2012 but it does not work.

To be more specific. VS2012 does not format the c# code when typing. Formatting works when typing in JavaScript section (cshtml) and everywhere on paste.

Thoughts?

Please help. I don't have time to reinstall but work in this way is suicide. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost. I am forced to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it really quick try installing [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) (there is trial version also). It has it's own formatting and I think it should override the VS one.

Comment: This is not a solution for me. :(